# Twitter Widget behind proxy

Tags: search, twitter, proxy, widget

I'm trying to use Twitter widget in a site which server is inside my corporation, hence, behind its proxy.

I can't use directly the code they provide, since I can't reach the source address.

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
```

I was wondering if I could make a local copy of the js so I could avoid this problem, but, when I did so I get:

```
ActionView::WrongEncodingError in Home#index
Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8. Please either specify UTF-8 as the encoding     for your template in your text editor, or mark the template with its encoding by inserting the following as the first line of the template:

# encoding: <name of correct encoding>.
```

But the encoding its already set.

I'm really really newby with this stuff.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is because ruby needs an explicit encoding to parse correctly a non latin-1 file.

In each ruby file that has utf-8 characters you need a first line like the example:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

As for the main problem in your question, you can try, but probably communication with twitter is blocked.
You should talk to your system administrator to try to get access to twitter for your app.